# Unity: AddTorque doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some obstacle like stick that is upright. It's move by velocity vector in rigibody2d (-4,0). And I have a hero which always stay in center of game screen. When hero collides with a stick, I want that obstacle flew away with some rotation, depending on the point of collision (like the laws of physics, if the collision point near the edges, then more torque).

But, AddTorque on rigibody2D doesn't work, although AddForce works fine.

There is code of collision

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{ 
    if (other.collider.tag == "Block")
    {
        if (InvBonusEnabled) {
            other.collider.isTrigger = true;
            other.rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
            other.rigidbody.AddTorque(100); //simple test doesn't work
            other.rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(200, 50));
           //  
        }
    }
}
```

I can't attach screen with prefab rigibody2D and collider2D settings (reputation 10 required on this stackoverflow)

*Rigibody2D*

Mass: 1

Linear Drag: 0

Angular Drag: 0.05

Gravity Scale: 1

IsKinematic: True

All Freeze Postion and Rotation are false

*Collider2D*

IsTrigger: false

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your torque may be too low of a number. Try upping it to the thousands or higher even.

Try also increasing the [`rigidbody.maxAngularVelocity`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-maxAngularVelocity.html) thats worked for me before

Comment: Set 10000000, doesn't wotk..

maxAngularVelocity not available for Rigidbody2D

Comment: you have `kinematic` set to `true`, then you set it to `false` in the code? Why not keep it off?

Comment: Because I want that obstacle move only horizontally before collision

Answer (score 0):

[`GameObject.rigidbody`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-rigidbody.html) and [`GameObject.rigidbody2D`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-rigidbody2D.html) have been deprecated. Try using `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` instead:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{ 
    if (other.collider.tag == "Block")
    {
        if (InvBonusEnabled) {
            other.collider.isTrigger = true;
            Rigidbody2D rb = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.isKinematic = false;
            rb.AddTorque(100);
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(200, 50));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only:
Rigidbody2D rb = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

But it still doesn't work